# Annotating type with class and instance

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

I'm making a semi-singleton class `Foo` that can have (also semi-singleton) subclasses. The constructor takes one argument, let's call it a `slug`, and each (sub)class is supposed to have at most one instance for each value of `slug`.

Let's say I have a subclass of `Foo` called `Bar`. Here is an example of calls:

1. `Foo("a slug")` -> returns a new instance of `Foo`, saved with key `(Foo, "a slug")`.
2. `Foo("some new slug")` -> returns a new instance `Foo`, saved with key `(Foo, "some new slug")`.
3. `Foo("a slug")` -> we have the same class and `slug` from step 1, so this returns the same instance that was returned in step 1.
4. `Bar("a slug")` -> we have the same slug as before, but a different class, so this returns a new instance of `Bar`, saved with key `(Bar, "a slug")`.
5. `Bar("a slug")` -> this returns the same instance of `Bar` that we got in step 4.

I know how to implement this: class dictionary associating a tuple of `type` and `str` to instance, override `__new__`, etc. Simple stuff.

My question is how to type annotate this dictionary?

What I tried to do was something like this:

```py
FooSubtype = TypeVar("FooSubtype", bound="Foo")

class Foo:
    _instances: Final[dict[tuple[Type[FooSubtype], str], FooSubtype]] = dict()
```

So, the idea is "whatever type is in the first element of the key ("assigning" it to `FooSubtype` type variable), the value needs to be an instance of that same type".

This fails with `Type variable "FooSubtype" is unbound`, and I kinda see why.

I get the same error if I split it like this:

```py
FooSubtype = TypeVar("FooSubtype", bound="Foo")
InstancesKeyType: TypeAlias = tuple[Type[FooSubtype], str]

class Foo:
    _instances: Final[dict[InstancesKeyType, FooSubtype]] = dict()
```

The error points to the last line in this example, meaning it's the value type, not the key one, that is the problem.

`mypy` also suggests using `Generic`, but I don't see how to do it in this particular example, because the value's type should somehow relate to the key's type, not be a separate generic type.

This works:

```py
class Foo:
    _instances: Final[dict[tuple[Type["Foo"], str], "Foo"]] = dict()
```

but it allows `_instance[(Bar1, "x")]` to be of type `Bar2` (`Bar1` and `Bar2` here being different subclasses of `Foo`). It's not a big problem and I'm ok with leaving it like this, but I'm wondering if there is a better (stricter) approach.

Comment: "This fails with Type variable "FooSubtype" is unbound, and I kinda see why." You have a typo in `TypeVar("FooSubtype", bind="Foo")` its `bound` not `bind` (see [`TypeVar` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeVar)).

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't. `typing.Final` is a read-only version of `typing.ClassVar`, and `typing.ClassVar` cannot contain any generic type variables. See e.g. https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/5144#issuecomment-439467090 and similar.

Comment: I'd go with [something like this](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.10&flags=strict%2Cdisallow-any-generics%2Cdisallow-incomplete-defs%2Cdisallow-subclassing-any%2Cdisallow-untyped-calls%2Cdisallow-untyped-decorators%2Cdisallow-untyped-defs%2Cno-implicit-optional%2Cwarn-redundant-casts%2Cwarn-unreachable%2Cwarn-unused-ignores&gist=192bc630fb5d8fb7426f415e280cfcf9). This gives proper `__getitem__` type, but still allows `_instances[(Foo1, 'foo')] = Foo2()`.

Comment: @ljmc, fixed, thank you. It was just a typo. The original code has it correct, of course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a really great question. First I looked through and said "no, you can't at all", because you can't express any relation between dict key and value. However, then I realised that your suggestion is almost possible to implement.

First, let's define a protocol that describes your desired behavior:

```py
from typing import TypeAlias, TypeVar, Protocol

_T = TypeVar("_T", bound="Foo")
# Avoid repetition, it's just a generic alias
_KeyT: TypeAlias = tuple[type[_T], str]  

class _CacheDict(Protocol):
    def __getitem__(self, __key: _KeyT[_T]) -> _T: ...
    def __delitem__(self, __key: _KeyT['Foo']) -> None: ...
    def __setitem__(self, __key: _KeyT[_T], __value: _T) -> None: ...
```

How does it work? It defines an arbitrary data structure with item access, such that `cache_dict[(Foo1, 'foo')]` resolves to type `Foo1`. It looks very much like a `dict` sub-part (or `collections.abc.MutableMapping`), but with slightly different typing. Dunder argument names are almost equivalent to positional-only arguments (with `/`). If you need other methods (e.g. `get` or `pop`), add them to this definition as well (you may want to use `overload`). You'll almost certainly need `__contains__` which should have the same signature as `__delitem__`.

So, now

```
class Foo:
    _instances: Final[_CacheDict] = cast(_CacheDict, dict())

class Foo1(Foo): pass
class Foo2(Foo): pass

reveal_type(Foo._instances[(Foo, 'foo')])  # N: Revealed type is "__main__.Foo"
reveal_type(Foo._instances[(Foo1, 'foo')])  # N: Revealed type is "__main__.Foo1"
```

wow, we have properly inferred value types! We cast `dict` to the desired type, because our typing is different from `dict` definitions.

It still has a problem: you can do

```
Foo._instances[(Foo1, 'foo')] = Foo2()
```

because `_T` just resolves to `Foo` here. However, this problem is completely unavoidable: even had we some `infer` keyword or `Infer` special form to spell `def __setitem__(self, __key: _KeyT[Infer[_T]], __value: _T) -> None`, it won't work properly:

```
foo1_t: type[Foo] = Foo1  # Ok, upcasting
foo2: Foo = Foo2()  # Ok again
Foo._instances[(foo1_t, 'foo')] = foo2  # Ough, still allowed, _T is Foo again
```

Note that we don't use any casts above, so this code is type-safe, but certainly conflicts with our intent.

So, we probably have to live with `__setitem__` unstrictness, but at least have proper type from item access.

Finally, the class is not generic in `_T`, because otherwise all values will be inferred to declared type instead of function-scoped (you can try using `Protocol[_T]` as a base class and watch what's happening, it's pretty good for deeper understanding of `mypy` approach to type inference).

Here's a link to [playground](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.10&flags=strict%2Cdisallow-any-generics%2Cdisallow-incomplete-defs%2Cdisallow-subclassing-any%2Cdisallow-untyped-calls%2Cdisallow-untyped-decorators%2Cdisallow-untyped-defs%2Cno-implicit-optional%2Cwarn-redundant-casts%2Cwarn-unreachable%2Cwarn-unused-ignores&gist=b3e462611d1fdc0752d1de4fa9d753f4) with full code.

Also, you can subclass a `MutableMapping[_KeyT['Foo'], 'Foo']` to get more methods instead of defining them manually. It will deal with `__delitem__` and `__contains__` out of the box, but `__setitem__` and `__getitem__` still need your implementation.

Here's an alternative solution with `MutableMapping` and `get` (because `get` was tricky and funny to implement) ([playground](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.10&flags=strict%2Cdisallow-any-generics%2Cdisallow-incomplete-defs%2Cdisallow-subclassing-any%2Cdisallow-untyped-calls%2Cdisallow-untyped-decorators%2Cdisallow-untyped-defs%2Cno-implicit-optional%2Cwarn-redundant-casts%2Cwarn-unreachable%2Cwarn-unused-ignores&gist=c92648804854395420eaae6f586f0193)):

```py
from collections.abc import MutableMapping
from abc import abstractmethod
from typing import TypeAlias, TypeVar, Final, TYPE_CHECKING, cast, overload


_T = TypeVar("_T", bound="Foo")
_Q = TypeVar("_Q")
_KeyT: TypeAlias = tuple[type[_T], str]

class _CacheDict(MutableMapping[_KeyT['Foo'], 'Foo']):
    @abstractmethod
    def __getitem__(self, __key: _KeyT[_T]) -> _T: ...
    @abstractmethod
    def __setitem__(self, __key: _KeyT[_T], __value: _T) -> None: ...
    
    @overload  # No-default version
    @abstractmethod
    def get(self, __key: _KeyT[_T]) -> _T | None: ...
    
    # Ooops, a `mypy` bug, try to replace with `__default: _T | _Q`
    # and check Foo._instances.get((Foo1, 'foo'), Foo2())
    # The type gets broader, but resolves to more specific one in a wrong way
    @overload  # Some default
    @abstractmethod
    def get(self, __key: _KeyT[_T], __default: _Q) -> _T | _Q: ...
    
    # Need this because of https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/11488
    @abstractmethod
    def get(self, __key: _KeyT[_T], __default: object = None) -> _T | object: ...


class Foo:
    _instances: Final[_CacheDict] = cast(_CacheDict, dict())

class Foo1(Foo): pass
class Foo2(Foo): pass

reveal_type(Foo._instances)
reveal_type(Foo._instances[(Foo, 'foo')])  # N: Revealed type is "__main__.Foo"
reveal_type(Foo._instances[(Foo1, 'foo')])  # N: Revealed type is "__main__.Foo1"
reveal_type(Foo._instances.get((Foo, 'foo')))  # N: Revealed type is "Union[__main__.Foo, None]"
reveal_type(Foo._instances.get((Foo1, 'foo')))  # N: Revealed type is "Union[__main__.Foo1, None]"
reveal_type(Foo._instances.get((Foo1, 'foo'), Foo1()))  # N: Revealed type is "__main__.Foo1"
reveal_type(Foo._instances.get((Foo1, 'foo'), Foo2()))  # N: Revealed type is "Union[__main__.Foo1, __main__.Foo2]"
(Foo1, 'foo') in Foo._instances  # We get this for free

Foo._instances[(Foo1, 'foo')] = Foo1()
Foo._instances[(Foo1, 'foo')] = object()  # E: Value of type variable "_T" of "__setitem__" of "_CacheDict" cannot be "object"  [type-var]
```

Note that we don't use a `Protocol` now (because it needs `MutableMapping` to be a protocol as well) and use abstract methods instead.

## Trick, don't use it!

When I was writing this answer, I discovered a `mypy` bug that you can abuse in a very interesting way here. We started with something like this, right?

```py
from collections.abc import MutableMapping
from abc import abstractmethod
from typing import TypeAlias, TypeVar, Final, TYPE_CHECKING, cast, overload


_T = TypeVar("_T", bound="Foo")
_Q = TypeVar("_Q")
_KeyT: TypeAlias = tuple[type[_T], str]

class _CacheDict(MutableMapping[_KeyT['Foo'], 'Foo']):
    @abstractmethod
    def __getitem__(self, __key: _KeyT[_T]) -> _T: ...
    @abstractmethod
    def __setitem__(self, __key: _KeyT[_T], __value: _T) -> None: ...
    
class Foo:
    _instances: Final[_CacheDict] = cast(_CacheDict, dict())

class Foo1(Foo): pass
class Foo2(Foo): pass

Foo._instances[(Foo1, 'foo')] = Foo1()
Foo._instances[(Foo1, 'foo')] = Foo2()
```

Now let's change `__setitem__` signature to a **very** weird thing. **Warning: this is a bug, don't rely on this behavior!** If we type `__default` as `_T | _Q`, we magically get "proper" typing with strict narrowing to type of first argument.

```
    @abstractmethod
    def __setitem__(self, __key: _KeyT[_T], __value: _T | _Q) -> None: ...
```

Now:

```
Foo._instances[(Foo1, 'foo')] = Foo1()  # Ok
Foo._instances[(Foo1, 'foo')] = Foo2()  # E: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Foo2", target has type "Foo1")  [assignment]
```

It is simply wrong, because `_Q` union part can be resolved to anything and is not used in fact (and moreover, it can't be a typevar at all, because it's used only once in the definition).

Also, this allows another invalid assignment, when right side is not a `Foo` subclass:

```py
Foo._instances[(Foo1, 'foo')] = object()  # passes
```

I'll report this soon and link the issue to this question.

Comment: Thank you so much! I think I get it all (except for how/why the bug works, but that's the nature of bugs). I do have two followup questions: 1. Why do `__key` and `__value` start with `__` as if they were private variables? Is it your way of doing things or some standard that I am not aware of? 2. When something, say `__getitem__`, returns some time (`_T` in this example), it means "instance of `_T` or of a sublass of `_T`, right? And there is no way way to say "it must be instance of exactly `_T` and not of its subclass, right?

Comment: 1. Dunder argument names are almost equivalent to positional-only arguments (with /) - I'm basically asking `mypy` to ignore the names and treat them as positional ([docs](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/protocols.html#callback-protocols)). 2. Yes, exactly, and "exactly _T and not its subclass" makes no sense in fact: why should `class A: ...` and `class B(A): pass` be treated somewhat differently? They work in the same way unless some heavy meta-programming is involved - it's basically what [LSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) enforces.

Comment: In my `__new__`, when I do `result = cls._instances[(cls, slug)]` (where `cls` is variable holding a sublcass of `Foo`), I get `Need type annotation for "result"` error from mypy. Declaring it as `result: cls` or using `cast(cls, ...)` expectedly fails (because `cls` is not a proper type; it's a variable that _contains_ one, making it dynamic, not static). Is there a better solution than declaring it as `result: Foo` (since I kinda _know_ that they type is the same as whatever is in `cls`)?

Comment: @VedranŠego Please post that as separate question or at least add that new code to question body. Blindly guessing, I suggest casting to `TypeVar` which is used in `__new__` definition, but it's weird that type inference fails here.

Comment: Also my first guess fails, the [following code](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.10&flags=strict%2Cdisallow-any-generics%2Cdisallow-incomplete-defs%2Cdisallow-subclassing-any%2Cdisallow-untyped-calls%2Cdisallow-untyped-decorators%2Cdisallow-untyped-defs%2Cno-implicit-optional%2Cwarn-redundant-casts%2Cwarn-unreachable%2Cwarn-unused-ignores&gist=a0bfad0cc80fde8e9fe1c606bc3995a9) (quite obvious) passes, so you're doing something less trivial probably. Ask a new question.

Comment: That example solved it, thank you. I usually don't declare types of `cls` and `self`. Adding `cls` type (and the return type for `__new__`) solved it. I was planning on using `Self` in the future, but not yet, as `Self` did not exist before Python 3.11, so it's a bit too new for redistributable code. Thank you again!

Comment: Usually you annotate `self` and `cls` only to bind the type variable, otherwise it is neither necessary not recommended.

Comment: I meant to use [`Self`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Self), introduced to `typing` in Python 3.11.